# SSRS encountered an unhandled exception

Tags: c#, web-services, reporting-services, asmx, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a windows service which calls ReportExecution2005.asmx web service and generates reports in PDF format. It works fine 95% of the time however from time to time we get below error. Its hard to reproduce so I am not able to figure out where it fails.

If I run the SSRS report Independently from SSRS admin website, than I never see this kind of error.

Has anyone encountered this kind of issue ? How can I get more information on the error ?

```
20160809_00:15:12.702[Error]Exception, Failed to Process Report : 
[ErrorMessage]:Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            SQL Server Reporting Services
        </title><meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services 11.0.5343.0" />
<meta name="HTTP Status" content="500" />
<meta name="ProductLocaleID" content="127" />
<meta name="CountryLocaleID" content="1033" />
<style>
            BODY {FONT-FAMILY:Verdana; FONT-WEIGHT:normal; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; COLOR:black}
            H1 {FONT-FAMILY:Verdana; FONT-WEIGHT:700; FONT-SIZE:15pt}
            LI {FONT-FAMILY:Verdana; FONT-WEIGHT:normal; FONT-SIZE:8pt; DISPLAY:inline}
            .ProductInfo {FONT-FAMILY:Verdana; FONT-WEIGHT:bold; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; COLOR:gray}
            A:link {FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-FAMILY:Verdana; COLOR:#3366CC; TEXT-DECORATION:none}
            A:hover {FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-FAMILY:Verdana; COLOR:#FF3300; TEXT-DECORATION:underline}
            A:visited {FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-FAMILY:Verdana; COLOR:#3366CC; TEXT-DECORATION:none}
            A:visited:hover {FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-FAMILY:Verdana; color:#FF3300; TEXT-DECORATION:underline}

        </style>
    </head><body bgcolor="white">
        <h1>
            Reporting Services Error<hr width="100%" size="1" color="silver" />
        </h1><ul>
            <li>The report server encountered an unhandled exception in HttpApplication. (rsUnhandledHttpApplicationError) <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&EvtID=rsUnhandledHttpApplicationError&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&ProdVer=11.0.5343.0" target="_blank">Get Online Help</a></li><ul>
                <li>For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors</li>
            </ul><hr width="100%" size="1" color="silver" /><span class="ProductInfo">SQL Server Reporting Services</span>
        </ul>
    </body>
--.
[StackTrace]:   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at RC.Common.reportexecution2005.ReportExecutionService.Render(String Format, String DeviceInfo, String& Extension, String& MimeType, String& Encoding, Warning[]& Warnings, String[]& StreamIds)
   at RC.Common.Worker.ReportWorker.GenerateReport(JobReportDto jobReportDTO)
   at RC.Common.Worker.ReportWorker.Execute(JobDto jobDto, String ServiceName)
****************************** [Thread:18828]
```

Comment: SSRS writes to text logs which will very likely contain more details.  The files should be in ` \Microsoft SQL Server\<SQL Server Instance>\Reporting Services\LogFiles`  On my machine, which has dev instance of SSRS, this is location is: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.DEV\Reporting Services\Logfiles\`

Comment: Yes I looked under there, cant find much info about this error.